# Xcode Error/Report a Bug Message on Top of Standard Editor

Tags: xcode

My Xcode 10.1 shows and hides "Report a Bug" message frequently when coding.

> The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagosticReports and has a
>   prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent
>   crash log. Report a Bug

.

It pushs editor down when it shows and up as disappears. Very annoying. [image]Is there anyway I can turn this off?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to turn off this feature (though of course it would be better if you just avoided playgrounds altogether, as they are pretty terrible in any case).

On the contrary, you should do what the message asks you to do. No matter how atrocious your code is, the Swift compiler should not crash; if it does, you should report it to Apple as requested.